# Generating random numbers with Swift

Tags: swift, arc4random

I need to generate a random number.

It appears the `arc4random` function no longer exists as well as the `arc4random_uniform` function.

The options I have are `arc4random_stir()`,   `arc4random_buf(UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, Int)`, and   `arc4random_addrandom(UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>, Int32)`.

I can't find any docs on the functions and no comments in the header files give hints.

Comment: It would appear that the auto-complete in Xcode was just broke. I could have sworn I typed it without auto-complete and it didn't compile. Working now. Nice reference by @arsen

Comment: arc4random_uniform is available.  It is part of the Foundation API not a native part of the language, so you need an "import Foundation" (or "import UIKit") at the head of the file to make it available.

Comment: probability = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(total))) – because the typeahead is broken, the typing complaints were non-specific, that was my casting complaint coming from two different errors

Answer (score 231, accepted):

```
let randomIntFrom0To10 = Int.random(in: 1..<10)
let randomFloat = Float.random(in: 0..<1)

// if you want to get a random element in an array
let greetings = ["hey", "hi", "hello", "hola"]
greetings.randomElement()
```

Comment: `Float.random()` is currently marked *Beta*, and so gives `'Float' has no member 'random'`

Answer (score 23):

You could try as well:

```
let diceRoll = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(6)))
```

I had to add "UInt32" to make it work.

Comment: When I look up this function I see `public func arc4random_uniform(_: UInt32) -> UInt32`. So I'm wondering why convert to the parameter to `UInt32`? Is something else happening here?

Answer (score 8):

Just call this function and provide minimum and maximum range of number and you will get a random number.

eg.like **randomNumber(MIN: 0, MAX: 10)** and  You will get number between **0 to 9**.

```
func randomNumber(MIN: Int, MAX: Int)-> Int{
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(MAX-MIN)) + UInt32(MIN));
}
```

Note:- You will always get output an Integer number.

Comment: I think needs to be:

`func randomNumber(MIN: Int, MAX: Int)-> Int{
  return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(MAX-MIN)) + UInt32(MIN));
}
`

Answer (score 5):

After some investigation I wrote this:

```
import Foundation

struct Math {
   private static var seeded = false

   static func randomFractional() -> CGFloat {

      if !Math.seeded {
         let time = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)
         srand48(time)
         Math.seeded = true
      }

      return CGFloat(drand48())
   }
}
```

Now you can just do `Math.randomFraction()` to get random numbers [0..1[ without having to remember seeding first. Hope this helps someone :o)

Answer (score 5):

**Update with swift 4.2 :**

```
let randomInt = Int.random(in: 1..<5)
let randomFloat = Float.random(in: 1..<10)
let randomDouble = Double.random(in: 1...100)
let randomCGFloat = CGFloat.random(in: 1...1000)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use the [xorshift128plus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift#xorshift.2B) algorithm:

```
func xorshift128plus(seed0 : UInt64, _ seed1 : UInt64) -> () -> UInt64 {
    var state0 : UInt64 = seed0
    var state1 : UInt64 = seed1
    if state0 == 0 && state1 == 0 {
        state0 = 1 // both state variables cannot be 0
    }

    func rand() -> UInt64 {
        var s1 : UInt64 = state0
        let s0 : UInt64 = state1
        state0 = s0
        s1 ^= s1 << 23
        s1 ^= s1 >> 17
        s1 ^= s0
        s1 ^= s0 >> 26
        state1 = s1
        return UInt64.addWithOverflow(state0, state1).0
    }

    return rand
}
```

This algorithm has a period of 2^128 - 1 and passes all the tests of the [BigCrush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestU01) test suite. Note that while this is a high-quality pseudo-random number generator with a long period, ***it is not a cryptographically secure random number generator***.

You could seed it from the current time or any other random source of entropy. For example, if you had a function called `urand64()` that read a `UInt64` from `/dev/urandom`, you could use it like this:

```
let rand = xorshift128plus(urand64(), urand64())
for _ in 1...10 {
    print(rand())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let MAX : UInt32 = 9
let MIN : UInt32 = 1 
func randomNumber()
{
   var random_number = Int(arc4random_uniform(MAX) + MIN)
   print ("random = ", random_number);    
}
```

Comment: Why don't you provide an explanation for this code?

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3 :

It will generate random number between 0 to limit

```
let limit : UInt32 = 6
print("Random Number : \(arc4random_uniform(limit))")
```

Comment: and if i want to generate a random number from 5 to 10, not from 0 to n number

Comment: @Rishi From 5 to 10 would be `arc4random_uniform(6) + 5`

Answer (score 1):

My implementation as an Int extension. Will generate random numbers in range `from..<to`

```
public extension Int {
    static func random(from: Int, to: Int) -> Int {
        guard to > from else {
            assertionFailure("Can not generate negative random numbers")
            return 0
        }
        return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(to - from)) + UInt32(from))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I get a random number between 2 int's!

```
func randomNumber(MIN: Int, MAX: Int)-> Int{
    var list : [Int] = []
    for i in MIN...MAX {
        list.append(i)
    }
    return list[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(list.count)))]
}
```

usage:

```
print("My Random Number is: \(randomNumber(MIN:-10,MAX:10))")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use **GKMersenneTwisterRandomSource** from GameKit. The docs say:

> A deterministic pseudo-random source that generates random numbers
>   based on a mersenne twister algorithm. This is a deterministic random
>   source suitable for creating reliable gameplay mechanics. It is
>   slightly slower than an Arc4 source, but more random, in that it has a
>   longer period until repeating sequences. While deterministic, this is
>   not a cryptographic random source. It is however suitable for
>   obfuscation of gameplay data.

```
import GameKit

let minValue = 0
let maxValue = 100

var randomDistribution: GKRandomDistribution?
let randomSource = GKMersenneTwisterRandomSource()
randomDistribution = GKRandomDistribution(randomSource: randomSource, lowestValue: minValue, highestValue: maxValue)
let number = randomDistribution?.nextInt() ?? 0
print(number)
```

Example taken from Apple's sample code: https://github.com/carekit-apple/CareKit/blob/master/CareKitPrototypingTool/OCKPrototyper/CareKitPatient/RandomNumberGeneratorHelper.swift

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party

Using a function that allows you to change the size of the array and the range selection on the fly is the most versatile method. You can also use map so it's very concise. I use it in all of my performance testing/bench marking.

`elements` is the number of items in the array
only including numbers from `0...max`

```
func randArr(_ elements: Int, _ max: Int) -> [Int] {
        return (0..<elements).map{ _ in Int.random(in: 0...max) }
    }
```

Code Sense / Placeholders look like this.
`randArr(elements: Int, max: Int)`

10 elements in my array ranging from 0 to 1000.

```
randArr(10, 1000) // [554, 8, 54, 87, 10, 33, 349, 888, 2, 77]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this in specific rate:

```
let die = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
 let firstRoll = die[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(die.count)))]
 let secondRoll = die[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(die.count)))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets Code with Swift for the random number or random string :)

```
let quotes: NSArray = ["R", "A", "N", "D", "O", "M"]

      let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quotes.count))
      let quoteString = quotes[Int(randomNumber)]
      print(quoteString)
```

it will give you output randomly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that some numbers will repeat! so you need to do something like....

my totalQuestions was 47.

```
func getRandomNumbers(totalQuestions:Int) -> NSMutableArray
{

    var arrayOfRandomQuestions: [Int] = []

    print("arraySizeRequired = 40")
    print("totalQuestions = \(totalQuestions)")

    //This will output a 40 random numbers between 0 and totalQuestions (47)
    while arrayOfRandomQuestions.count < 40
    {

        let limit: UInt32 = UInt32(totalQuestions)

        let theRandomNumber = (Int(arc4random_uniform(limit)))

            if arrayOfRandomQuestions.contains(theRandomNumber)
            {
                print("ping")

            }
            else
            {
            //item not found
                arrayOfRandomQuestions.append(theRandomNumber)
            }

    }

    print("Random Number set = \(arrayOfRandomQuestions)")
    print("arrayOutputCount = \(arrayOfRandomQuestions.count)")


    return arrayOfRandomQuestions as! NSMutableArray

}
```

Answer (score -2):

look, i had the same problem but i insert
 the function as a global variable

as

```
var RNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(9)+1)

func GetCase(){

your code
}
```

obviously this is not efficent, so then i just copy and paste the code into the function so it could be reusable, then xcode suggest me to set the var as constant so my code were

```
func GetCase() {

let RNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(9)+1)

   if categoria == 1 {
    }
}
```

well thats a part of my code so xcode tell me something of inmutable and initialization but, it build the app anyway and that advice simply dissapear

hope it helps