# Generating random number on Swift 7.2

Tags: swift, function

To generate random number on swift 7.2 I was trying to use:

arc4random_uniform

but this functions doesnt work anymore on 7.2 version. Anyone knows how to solve this? I need to generate random numbers from 0 to infinite.

Thank you

Comment: It does still work. It is only missing in Xcode's autocompletion.

Comment: Look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32552336/generating-random-numbers-with-swift-2

Comment: might take a little bit of processing power to generate infinity... pretty big number