# how to generate random numbers from 1 to 4 and 8 in swift

Tags: ios, swift, random, sprite-kit, arc4random

I'm making an iOS SpriteKit game right now for first time I'm developing any app and it's tough challenge for me because it's really a big project for first time. My game is a Dice game and I defined move as 4 number. So when ever I touch the screen Player moves 4 blocks, But now I want to add Dice to the Game and I need Numbers from 1 to 4 and 8. So it will be 1,2,3,4 and 8 Numbers in the Dice. I know in Swift we can get Random Numbers with "arc4random" but how do I get numbers 1 to 4 and also 8 can I do it with arc4random and if possible I need 4 and 8 numbers to come 20% more often.
Any Help will be really Helpful. Thanks.

Comment: This might be helpful for you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32552336/generating-random-numbers-with-swift

Comment: See also [Generate random numbers with a given distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30309556/generate-random-numbers-with-a-given-distribution)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put your `sides` into an array and use [`randomElement()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/randomelement()) to perform the roll:

```
let sides = [1, 2, 3, 4, 8]
let roll = sides.randomElement()!
```

> if possible I need 4 and 8 numbers to come 20% more often

That means, `4` and `8` should come up 6 times for every time the others come up 5.  So put 5 of each of `1`-`3` in your array, and 6 each of `4` and `8`:

```
let sides = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]
let roll = sides.randomElement()!
```

**Note:** It is perfectly safe and appropriate to *force unwrap* the result of `randomElement()` with `!` here because `randomElement()` only returns `nil` when the collection is empty, and we know it’s not.

---

Also, check out [MartinR's `randomNumber(probabilities:)` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30309951/1630618).

You'd use his function like this:

```
let sides = [1, 2, 3, 4, 8]
let probabilities = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.2, 1.2]

let rand = randomNumber(probabilities: probabilities)
let roll = sides[rand]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a random number from 1-8, and if 5,6,7 comes, you can run the random number function again until an acceptable value.
Its kinda a workaround, but it works because the dataset is small.

Comment: you can in theory cause your game to freeze with this.  What if you have the very unfortunate luck of always randomly getting 5?  You will never break out of your loop then.