# Swift random element with probability

Tags: swift, random, probability

It seems like `randomElement()` in Swift only allows for an equally weighted selection. What would be the best (and most efficient way, as I need to repeat this very often) to select from a collection with pre-specified probabilities/weights?

Comment: I saw that post, but is that really the most efficient way? It seems quite involved with the for loops etc.
As said above, this should be as fast as possible.

Comment: [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51122606/1630618) uses multiple copies of the elements to weight the choices and is very fast in specific cases.